# Storing DOM element reference in JavaScript Array. Why cant I reuse stored reference to add eventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, reference

I'm afraid it might be a silly question, but I have no idea what occurs my problem.

I dynamically create buttons (each button has unique id), and I store each btn reference (document.getElementById()) in simple two-dimensional array. All these because i need to hold btns in well organized structure.

---

**The problem is:** when i try to modify element by reference previously stored in my array, there appears to be no connection between ref and html element.

---

```
var Table = {
size: 10,
table: [],
generateTable: function() {
  var i = 0,
    j = 0,
    id = null,
    tablePlaceholder = document.getElementById("tableHTML");

  //Generate table
  for (i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
    this.table.push([]);
    for (j = 0; j < this.size; j++) {
      id = i.toString() + "-" + j.toString();
      tablePlaceholder.innerHTML += element(id);
      this.table[i].push(document.getElementById(id));
    }
    tablePlaceholder.innerHTML += "</br>";
  }



  console.log(this.table[0][0].className);
  document.getElementById("0-0").className += " btn-success";
  console.log(this.table[0][0].className);
}, ...
```

---

Results of last two console.logs is the same, but element has changed in DOM.
table[0][0] returns same content as `document.getElementById("0-0")`.
(element() function returns simple html code (it works well))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
innerHTML += '<div>...</div>';
```

This could break references to already constructed DOM elements and cause other chaos. In reality, all you want to do is append a single new element to the end.

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.id = id;
tablePlaceholder.appendChild(elem);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: I've just read an article about "Why not to use innerHTML" and oh my God, I'm never going to use it again. Changing innerHTML, to creating and adding separate nodes resolved my problem. Thank you for your answer !